# Google Sheets incorrect conditional formatting result

Tags: google-sheets

this is not really programmatical question but I have no idea where else to ask.

[image]

As what screenshot shows, my conditional formatting is set to > 0 red, == 0 green, but there's just this one cell which stucks at red, anyone have any idea why?

Thank you.

Comment: Besides being unrelated to programming, this also don't have a MCVE. The only way people can answer that is to guess the problem.

Comment: @user202729 Do you have any idea where should I post this to?

Comment: Well it could be that the value is greater than zero, such as 0.001, which would be correctly red, while displayed as 0.0. If that's not it, post a link to the sheet and should be fixable OK.

Comment: @bcperth made a copy of the doc here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SadRupbgZzEh9V_UpXEtkML8JXABV6v5WRFwIhe-UlM/edit?usp=sharing, take note at cell K37, don't think its decimal place issue

Comment: See my reply below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my first comment above the problem is precision. Take a look at this with your sheet when formatted to display 16 decimal places.

[image]

The offending cell which should be `0.00` is in fact `0.0000000000000071054`, and the format formula is correct to colour it red!

**Why?**  In general when using floating point numbers the precision is limited based on the internal length of the numbers being stored with 64 bit being common. So they are not exact.

This means its hazardous to do do exact comparisons on floating point numbers. The results can be surprising as your example shows, if you don't understand how floats behave. You can search on line for more details. The crux of the matter is that you need to test if the difference is greater or less than some small number - like 0.0000001 for example. A workable test for "equality" would be `abs(a-b) < 0.00000001`.

**Workaround:** The simplest in your case would be to replace the formulas in column K with `round(H23-J23,8)` for row 23 for example. Then your conditional formula will work fine in all cases.

Comment: wow, i tried increasing the decimal places but not until 16 decimal places =/

Comment: Yes I tried less than 16 places initially, but I was sure of the cause, so I keep increasing until the culprit was exposed. It's hard to find where the float resolution is defined for Sheets, but if you read here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754 you will see in the first table that binary16 has 15.95 decimal digits ie 15 - which looks close! So digits after that are undefined. I think Google does not handle this well.